# In how many ways can one fill a $m×n$ table with $±1$ such that the product of entries in each row and each column is $-1$?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

I have almost solved the question but I am stuck in the last part we know $X_1 , X_2,......,X_{(n-1)}$ and $Y_1, Y_2 ,.....Y_{(n-1)}$ can be filled only in one way, so the question reduces to filling the $(n-1) \times (m-1)$ table with $±1$ with out any condition i.e $2^{(n-1)(m-1)}$ but what about the green ( right bottom) box how can we fill that box?

Answer (score 2):

Good work up to here.  Now as you say, the question is whether we can fill in the lower right-hand corner consistently.  In order to be able to do this, the product of the elements in the last column (except for the element in the lower right-hand corner of course) must be equal to the product of the elements in the the last row (again except for the lower right-hand corner).

When is this true?

**Hint**: Think about the product of all the numbers that are neither in the last column nor the last row.

**Another Hint** Let $P$ be the product of all the numbers that are neither in the last row nor the last column.  The product of all the numbers in the first $n-1$ rows is $(-1)^{n-1},$ so the product of all the numbers in the last column, except for the one in the lower right-hand corner is $$\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{P}$$
Make a similar argument about the last row.  What can you conclude now?

Comment: Naah, can't figure out when that is true.

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about , the  product of all the numbers in the first n−1 rows is (−1)^n−1 how? And 'all the numbers in the first n−1 rows' what does this mean.  I think I am missing some concepts ( meaning -  may be I have not studied some concepts)  that are required to solve this problem yet.

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about , the  product of all the numbers in the first n−1 rows is (−1)^n−1 how? And 'all the numbers in the first n−1 rows' what does this mean.  I think I am missing some concepts ( meaning - I have not studied some concepts)  that are required to solve this problem yet.

Comment: the product of all the numbers in the last column, except for the one in the lower right-hand corner is
(−1)^n−1/P  how?

Comment: Ok now I think I am  getting to understand what you are trying to say .

Comment: The product of the elements in each row is -1, so the product of all the elements in those row is $(-1)^{n-1}.$  The product of all the elements is in the first $n-1$ rows is the product of those in the last column times the product of those *not* in the last column.  I doubt this relies on any concepts you haven't studied.  You learned that multiplication is commutative and associative a long time ago, I should think.

Comment: Ok I have understood now  ,so the product of all the numbers in the last column, except for the one in the lower right-hand corner is (-1)^(m-1)/P which implies that m has to be equal to n to fill in the lower right-hand corner consistently. Thanks man for your time and effort.

Comment: You still haven't got it, I'm afraid.  You need $(-1)^n=(-1)^m$ but that doesn't require $n=m$.  What if $m=4, n=2?$

Comment: Aaah my bad ok so that implies m and n have to have same parity .

Comment: Yes, that's it.